# How to massage numpy function arguments

Tags: python, numpy

Unluckily it is not possible to get numpy function arguments with inspect because they are not python code. However from the manual we can easily retrieve descriptions like

```
 uniform([low, high, size])
 triangular(left, mode, right[, size])
```

For purposes of linking to Excel, it would suffice to convert them to

```
 uniform(low=None, high=None, size=None)
 triangular(left, mode, right, size=None)
```

I'm sure this conversion can be automated, but my knowledge of string handling in Python is scarce and any suggestion on how to do it would be welcome.

Comment: What is wrong with he original `uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=None)`?

Comment: I'm afraid this is too vague and general at present: can you be more specific?  What do you mean, "manual"?  In what context do you want to do this?  How are you planning to link to Excel?  Pose a specific question, ideally with some code, or at least, pseudo-code.

Comment: Nothing wrong with "uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=None)". But I dont know how to retrieve it given "uniform".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would use [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getdoc) to do this (and I suggest you look at this module) but a quick and somewhat dirty approach would be to parse the docstrings of the methods you want. This gives most of the method prototypes in the format you want (depending on how the docstrings are written), and you could then clean up the others manually:

```
import numpy as np

for method_name, method in np.random.__dict__.items():
    try:
        docstring_lines = method.__doc__.split('\n')
    except (AttributeError,):
        continue
    if len(docstring_lines) == 0:
        continue
    for line in docstring_lines:
        if method_name in line:
            print(line.strip())
            break
```

e.g.

```
power(a, size=None)
get_state()
multivariate_normal(mean, cov[, size])       # <-- NB needs cleaning up
gamma(shape, scale=1.0, size=None)
random_sample(size=None)
random_sample(size=None)
standard_cauchy(size=None)
choice(a, size=None, replace=True, p=None)
...
```

Comment: The samples look ok, except the cleanup still needed. Anyway I will take the suggestion of having a look to inspect